# How to read the legend text along with the radio button label when the focus is on radio button

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, narrator

I have a radio button and a  on top of it. When the narrator focus is on the radio button it just reads the value of radio button. But I want it to read the text value of the  also.

[Code and UI snapshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWlZ5.png

Here is the code

```
<html>

<body>
<legend class="leg">Read this also</legend>
<label class="c-label">
    <input type="radio" name="1" value="2" aria-label="yes" />
    <span class="yes">yes</span>
</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected to read the text of the  tag along with the radio button when the narrator focus is on radio button, i.e. "Read this also Yes radio button unselected radio button 1 of 1"

Actual output is, narrator is just reading the value of radio button, i.e "Yes radio button unselected radio button 1 of 1"

Answer (score 0):

The [`legend` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-legend-element) is not meant to be used on its own but only as the first child of the `fieldset` element.

The `fieldset` element can be used to group a number of related form elements; the `legend` element provides a label for the `fieldset`. The length of the `legend` element should be kept short, since screen readers would typically read it for every input element inside the `fieldset`.

If the intent of the form is for the user to confirm that he/she has read something (e.g. terms and conditions), then the better approach is to leave out the `fieldset` and `legend` elements and just use a checkbox (instead of a radio button) with a proper `label` element instead of a `span` element:

```
 <form>
   <!-- possibly other form fields -->
   <input type="checkbox" name="readconditions" id="rdcond" value="readconditions" /> 
   <label for="rdcond">I have read the terms and conditions</label>
   <!-- possibly other form fields, including a submit button -->
 </form>
```